# Has anyone tried to embed a flash into a webpage so it can be displayed to anyone

Tags: android, flash, webview, embed

Has anyone tried or is it possible to embed a flash into a webpage so it can be displayed in an android that doesnt have flash player installed?

An example of what I am talking about is googles:

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=www.pdfxxx.com/PDFFILE.PDF

where you can embed pdf document links and view them.

Is it possible to do the same with a flash webpage link?

Kind regards!

Comment: Don't get this wrong, but if you **need** flash player to play flash movies, how can you play flash movies **without** flash player installed? It's kinda simple logic - no flash player, no movie.

Comment: What I meant was if there were some type of converting tool/method available online but I actually found a solution. Thanks for downvoting me because the solution doesn't exist as of today that you know of.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is a client side technology, while a PDF is essentially a big document.

You can render documents as images on a server and send them to the browser, but as far as I know no such service exists for flash technologies, and flash must be installed on the client for it to work.

Comment: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 1):

What you could do (as a workaround) is as of CS6, Flash has included the Swiffy HTML5 conversion plug in. Go to Commands - Export as HTML5 Swiffy (I think you can even manually install it if you don't have CS6).

This works most of the time, but it isn't perfect, so it may or may not work for your Fla depending on the complexity. I believe animation would work better than interactive stuff.

You said you found a solution. Could you please share?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, that is the same thing I saw!